# Datetime Format in Month and Year

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to format a datetime column like so: "March 2004." Currently, I tried

```
    DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(20) = '2004-03-05 01:00'

    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST(@Date AS DATETIME),13) AS DateFormats
```

but not getting the right result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(20) = '2004-03-05 01:00'
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, @Date) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, @Date)
```

More on `DATENAME` can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174395.aspx

Essentially it gets the month part of the date and the year part of the date and concatenate them together.

Answer (score 2):

You should really apply formatting when you present your data, not in the query, but to answer the question, if you're using SQL Server 2012 or above you can use [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213505.aspx)

```
DECLARE @Date datetime = '2004-03-05 01:00'
SELECT FORMAT( @Date, 'MMMM yyyy' ) AS DateFormats
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the built-in formats include the full month.  Instead, use `datename()`:

```
select datename(month, @date) + ' ' + datename(year, @date)
```